# Is the Great Weapon Master feat's +10 damage bonus added on top of your ability score modifier?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, damage, ability-scores

Using the Great Weapon Master feat, do you add the 10 damage bonus on top of the strength modifiers or is it just add 10 without the strength modifiers?

Comment: I made the wording a bit clearer based on your feedback on the answer you got. If this isn't what you were asking, feel free to revert.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the PHB (emphasis mine):

> Before you make a melee attack with a heavy weapon that you are proficient with, you can choose to take a -5 penalty to the attack roll. If the attack hits, you add +10 **to the attack's damage**.

When you roll to hit, you roll d20, and add your strength modifier, and your proficiency. If you roll higher than the target's AC, it is a successful hit. When you roll for damage, you roll the weapon's damage dice (for a greatsword, it's 2d6), and you add your strength modifier only.

This means, with the GWM feat, that when you make the attack, you roll d20 + str + prof - 5. The attack damage, if successful, is (in the case of a greatsword): 2d6 + str + 10.

Comment: Ok thank you I didn't know if the +10 was instead of the Strength modifier or in addition. Thanks for clearing it up!